# how to write absolute url for facebook static_html_plus app?

Tags: relative-path, absolute-path

I read articals regarding absolute and relative urls but still I am anable to find url to my [classifieds](http://www.sale65.com) site sale65.com

can any body reply what is my absolute url?

Comment: Absolute URL is a fully qualified URL : [protocol]://[subdomain.]domain.topleveldomain/[pathToASpecificItem] , the absolute url to the root of your site would then be `http://www.sale65.com/`

Comment: I used http://www.sale65.com/ URL in facebook app for getting dofollow link it is showing you entered relative path. you must enter absolute path.